# How to use PostgreSQL column value with some calculations as second column value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am inserting a huge data set into the SQL table and I want to achieve something like this.

```
SELECT generate_series(1,10) AS a, mod(generate_series(11,20),3) as b,mod(generate_series(21,30),5) as c;

 a  | b | c 
----+---+---
  1 | 2 | 1
  2 | 0 | 2
  3 | 1 | 3
  4 | 2 | 4
  5 | 0 | 0
  6 | 1 | 1
  7 | 2 | 2
  8 | 0 | 3
  9 | 1 | 4
 10 | 2 | 0
(10 rows)
```

The problem is I don't want to call generate_series function for `b` and `c`. I want to take the value of `a` and perform mod on it for `b` and `c` like below or even efficient way but I am unable to understand this how can I do it efficiently as I will be generating and saving **1 Million** records.

```
SELECT generate_series(1,10) AS a, mod(a,3) as b,mod(a,5) as c;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `from` clause:

```
SELECT a, mod(a, 3) as b, mod(a, 5) as c;
FROM generate_series(1,10) gs(a)
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is the purpose of `gs(a)`?

Comment: @KhubaibAhmad . . . That names the return value from `generate_series()` as `gs.a`.